# Knex where doesn't allow passing single string to `.where()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, typescript, knex.js

I have the following line in a program written in Node.js using Knex and SQLite:

```
await db.table("books")
         .innerJoin("items", "items.id", "books.item_id")
         .with("idx", db.raw(`instr(items.name, ?) asc`, name))
         .where("idx > 0")
         .orderBy("idx")
         .select()
```

Where `db` is a variable created by calling `knex(config)`. However, the function `raw(sql)` doesn't seem to work, as it keeps throwing this error at runtime:

> TypeError: The operator "undefined" is not permitted
>       at Formatter.operator (I:\git\server\node_modules\knex\lib\formatter.js:138:13)
>
> at QueryCompiler_SQLite3.whereBasic (I:\git\server\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:525:100)
>
> at QueryCompiler_SQLite3.where (I:\git\server\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:314:32)

What am I doing incorrectly?

If it's relevant, I'm writing in Typescript, and as you can see with `await`, I am using ES6. However, this query executes fine if I exclude the `with()`, and `with()` refuses to accept something that is not created by `raw()`.

Edit:

If I test this, it shows that the problem is in `with()` and not in `raw()`:

```
console.log("name: " + name);
console.log("db.raw(name): " + db.raw(`instr(items.name, ?) asc`, name));
```

Gives the expected output.

Comment: What is the value of the `name` variable?

Comment: @Matt if it matters, it's just a string like "hello world"

Comment: Just checking if that was the `undefined` value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with `where()`, which I didn't see until I inspected the stack trace more closely. Replacing `.where("idx > 0")` with `.where("idx", ">", 0)` fixed it.